# Dump postgresql without files data

Tags: dump, postgresql-9.4

We are saving in Postgresql 9.4 files in column **bytea**.

Is it possible to dump database without data of such columns? or whiout specific table?

Comment: You can exclude tables from pg_dump if that is what you mean. Check the `-T` parameter in the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy a table, then you can do it by using the copy keyword. It will copy the table without copying the data in the columns or rows.